# How to "hide" the real TextView value?

Tags: android, textview

I have textview fields, which should have seemingly the same value, but they should have a second "hidden" value, which I can test after clicking and do the right action for the value. So I would like to hide the real value of the textview fields.
What do you think, how can I do this?

Comment: caching / second invisible textbox / custom textbox with previous -current value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use-

```
textView.setvisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having "real" and "fake" values on your TextViews, why not instead have a couple of "real value" and "display value" variables holding your strings for you. You can easily swap them out after detecting that the supposedly "right action" is achieved.